# Sorting an array with simple algorithm but loop becomes infinite

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array elements. I have made a very simple algorithm of mine. Here is it

```
<html>
<head>  

    <script>

    var numberList = [44, 58, 12, 53, 25, 63];  

    for(var i = 0; i<numberList.length; i++){
        var reset = i;
        for(var j = 1; j<numberList.length; j++){
            if(numberList[j]<numberList[i]){
                var k = numberList[i];
                var l = numberList[j];
                numberList[i] = l;
                numberList[j] = k;
                i++;
            } else{
                var k = numberList[i];
                var l = numberList[j];
                numberList[i] = k;
                numberList[j] = l;
                i++;
            }                   
        }   
        i = reset;      
    } 
    document.write(numberList); 

    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is loop becomes infinite. Each time after execution of inner for loop, the value of variable i becomes 5. So I have introduced a variable named reset to restore the value of i. So that i is again set to it's primary value & then first for loop make an increment to it. But it becomes infinite. The same algorithm is working fine in another program. But here it's no. I appreciate your help.

Comment: why don't you just use `Array.prototype.sort()`?  Why re-invent the wheel for something that's already built into javascript environment

Comment: there is not just 1 problem with algorithm. First of all its complexity is n^2
secondly you are incrementing at wrong place.

Comment: The *else* block is redundant, it's just putting the members in their current locations (i.e. it doesn't move them anywhere).

Comment: Don't increment `i` inside the `j` loop.

Comment: @charlietfl Most probably the poster is trying to sharpen his skill in JS I suppose.

Comment: This seems to be an attempt at a classic bubble sort, however the trick is to start at 0 on each iteration, swap adjacent members that are out of order, and only stop when you no longer move any members.

Comment: Which sorting technique you want to implement?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I am just trying to enhance my JS skills so that I am not using a builtin method. I agree with RobG, it's a bubble sort method. Can you help me with variable i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
var numberList = [44, 58, 12, 53, 25, 63];  
    var intArrayLength = numberList.length;
    for(var i = 0; i <intArrayLength; i++){

        for(var j = i+1; j < intArrayLength; j++){

            if(numberList[i] > numberList[j] ){
                var swapNumber = numberList[j];
                numberList[j] = numberList[i];
                numberList[i] = swapNumber;
            }                  
        }   

    } 
    document.write(numberList);
```

EDIT :

inner for loop can be written in this way also without using temp variable.

```
for(var j = i+1; j < intArrayLength; j++){

            if(numberList[i] > numberList[j] ){
                numberList[j] += numberList[i];
                numberList[i] =  numberList[j]-numberList[i];
                numberList[j] =  numberList[j]-numberList[i];
            }                  
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the point in avoiding the temporary variable, especially as the above method modifies the values when they're moved, so it might not restore the exact same values (and assumes that they are numbers). The temporary variable is only created once and its value changed on each iteration only if members are out of sequence. Simple assignment should be faster than a sequence of mathematic operations, even if they're simple addition and subtraction. Also, I think the algorithm is incorrect, try it with the smallest value at the largest index.

Comment: @RobG I have given alternate option for swapping .I am not saying which one is faster or slow.And which one should use.

Answer (score 2):

When you increment i in scope of "j"-cycle, you do not check that i is less than array length. I.e. during execution of this cycle you refer to not existed element of array and add it to the array. So you need to change condition in the second for statement:

```
for(var i = 0; i<numberList.length; i++){
    var reset = i;
    for(var j = 1; j<numberList.length &&  i<numberList.length; j++){
```

So if we go step-by-step through you code, we can find the next:

```
i = 0, j = 1: [44, 58, 12, 53, 25, 63]
i = 1, j = 2: [44, 12, 58, 53, 25, 63]
i = 2, j = 3: [44, 12, 53, 58, 25, 63]
i = 3, j = 4: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]
i = 4, j = 5: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]

i = 1, j = 1: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]
i = 2, j = 2: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]
i = 3, j = 3: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]
i = 4, j = 4: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]
i = 5, j = 5: [44, 12, 53, 25, 58, 63]

i = 2, j = 1: [44, 53, 12, 25, 58, 63]
i = 3, j = 2: [44, 53, 25, 12, 58, 63]
i = 4, j = 3: [44, 53, 25, 58, 12, 63]
i = 5, j = 4: [44, 53, 25, 58, 63, 12]
i = 6, j = 5: // i == numberList.length
```

So that is a reason of yours infinite-loop

Comment: Actually answering the question? Now there's a novel concept…;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0; i<numberList.length-1; i++){ 
   for(var j = i+1; j<numberList.length; j++){
        if(numberList[j]<numberList[i]){
            var k = numberList[i];
            var l = numberList[j];
            numberList[i] = l;
            numberList[j] = k;
        }                   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time `i` is incremented, the value of `reset` is then set to the new `i` value.

When you have the line `i = reset;` it doesn't make any difference, because at the top you have already told it that `reset = i`. Try taking the reset variable out.

Also, the `.length` command will give back the number of values in the array. In this case `length = 6`. However, the final index of the array is actually number 5 because it starts at 0 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = 6 indices). So when `i` is 5, it is still less than the length and so the code you have written will increment `i` to 6, which is out of bounds on the array.
To fix this, you could change the code to read...

```
for(var i = 0; i< (numberList.length-1); i++)
```

so that when `i` is 5, it wont be incremented any further because 5 is the last index value of the array.

I hope that helps. (and makes sense :) )

Comment: for(var i = 0; i< (numberList.length-1); i++) won't help because this code refer to numberList[6], when initial value of i = 2, j = 5.    I.e. as a result of the very last i++ i become equal to 6